# XML header missing after converting an XML file into a Binary Format File

Tags: c#, xml, excel, arrays

I have a problem. I have an XML spreadsheet file that I'm trying to send via email. So I converted into a binary file and attached it to an email. The problem is when I'm trying to open it (on Excel), it's not showing the data that I saved. When I opened it like an XML file I realized that it didn't saved the XML header:

 The way it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
...
<Styles>
...
</Styles>
<Worksheet>
...
</Worksheet></Workbook>
```

after converting:

```
<Worksheet>
...
</Worksheet>
```

I've tried to use an xmldocument but i wasn't working,  I also tried using a string, still not working.
 This is how I convert the XML to binary:

```
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
binaryFile = encoding.GetBytes(xmlFile);
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding quite some of the involved concepts. But without having more details it's hard to guide you in the right direction. Just as an example: There is no need to convert xml files before attaching them to an email. Why do you think so?

Comment: I want to attached an XML file to an email, so I need to convert the file into a binary array so I can attached it to an email using the MailMessage  class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake: I didn't serialized the XML file so that's why after the conversion it just shows the data without the XML header. so there's 2 ways to resolve this problem: 
first, we can concatenate the header with the data string, or we can use the serialize function. [This is where I've found how to do it](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173).

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more information on how you're converting the XML file.

From your description it sounds like you've saved an Excel Spreadsheet to XML and for whatever reason you cannot just attach this text document to an email. My guess is you're using a method to attach the XML file that requires a byte array and can't just be provided a file location. If you could provide more information on this, it would help us figure out where things are going wrong for you.

The part I'm really stuck on is:

> I've tried to use an xmldocument but i wasn't working, I also tried
>   using a string, still not working.

How did you try string? Did you read the file from disk using FileStream? If so, you should have been able to retrieve the full contents of the file.

Were you using XmlDocument the whole time and trying XmlDocument.OuterXml? This probably won't give you the control headers since they're not part of the XML body inside the root node.

So really there are two things I would have tried. First, if I had an XML file on disk and needed to attach it to an email through code and my only option was to provide a byte array, I'd do something like:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] binaryFile = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(binaryFile, 0, buff.LongLength);

    //Copy the byte array to your email object.
}
```

Now if this isn't what you're doing, you'll need to provide a lot more detail on what you are starting with (file on disk?), what you need to do (send automated email?), what constraints you have and any other information that would limit potential solutions.